# How this out become 2 in javascript can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript

I just try this code on my console and got 2 as output

```
[1] - - [1]

output: 2
```

Can any one explain how the output become 2?

Comment: You should share with us your code and trying, please.

Comment: `[1] - - [1] => '1' - -'1' => '1' - -1 => 1 - -1 => 1 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you make mathematical expression, JS parses your array and converts it to int (try `+[1]`)
2. Simple math: `number minus negative number` becomes `number plus number`. So `1 -- 1 == 2`

Answer (score 0):

Single value arrays can also become int. JS has a typecast when it comes to integers. With integers, JS automatically typecast it to integer. So `"1" - - 1` will also result in `2`. same way `[1] - - [1]` is `2`, where as `[1,2] - - [1]` will give you `NaN`.

There should be space in between `-` because `--` without space, JS doesnt consider it to be a valid operand. Where as with space JS takes it as two different operands so in this case it ll take `-` `-1` which makes `+` and thus adds the two numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is correct.

`--` becomes `+`

so `1--1` is `2`

Comment: He has to update the post.. its an int and not actually a array..! Since he got the output as 2..!

Comment: @Bathsheba : To all downvoters for this thread. The post he mentioned everyone thinks that array since the post referred as [1] but in the same question, the post has the console output as 2. basically the post the user posted was the mistake in the input. So we have replied back with the logic of `--`.